# wkhtmltopdf: How can I use a file or text with footer-html?

Tags: html, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm using wkhtmltopdf to convert an html template into a pdf, and I want to use some html as a footer, but as far as I can tell I have to make the html a webpage, which means it would be visible to the public. So I have two questions:

1. Is there any way to use a string or a file with footer-html?
2. If not, is there any way to prevent the footer webpage from being visible to the public? I'm using flask to make my website.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer. I used 'footer-html': url_for(...) to get the path to the file. In the file I also had to change the css path (I used url_for, but wkhtmltopdf doesn't understand jinja). So I changed it to a static file path.